# JSON parsing issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a (probably) silly problem, but I can't undertand what's wrong ...
I request an AWS API Gateway URL, I have a json-formatted response, I parse it, but then when I want to get the value of a specific JSON element I get "undefined" instead of the element's value.

Here is my code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            data = jsonData.coord;
            document.write(data);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', "https://[mon-url]", true);
    xhr.send();
```

The API response is parsed using

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
document.write(jsonData)
```

give the following output :

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 2.35,
    "lat": 48.85
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 291.97,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "humidity": 56,
    "temp_min": 288.15,
    "temp_max": 295.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.1,
    "deg": 60
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1495747800,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5615,
    "message": 0.0022,
    "country": "FR",
    "sunrise": 1495684591,
    "sunset": 1495741168
  },
  "id": 2988507,
  "name": "Paris",
  "cod": 200
}
```

But if I try to get a specific element's value, for example using `document.write(jsonData.coord)` I get `"undefined"` as a value.

Can someone help me understand why I can't correctly parse my JSON data ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you also log the type of `jsonData`? `console.log(typeof(jsonData))`

Comment: @prasad, shouldn't make any difference if the data OP has added is in correct format

Comment: use `jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText))`

Comment: make jsonData a local variable. Where else do you change its value?

Comment: Puting simple words you are parsing two times the data. when you receive the data and when you send the data. Solution use @ farhadamjady solution or send a string. That's why I like to use '$ajax'. If you whant to lern more go to this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Rajesh FYI, `typeof` is not a function, it's an operator. The brackets are just noise, `console.log(typeof jsonData)` is more proper.

Comment: And you're building your json badly!

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Its a opinionated comment. You like it without parenthesis, I like it with them. There is no *more proper* way.

Comment: @Rajesh Not really, writing `typeof(variable)` is just messy the same way that something like `(varOne) + (varTwo) - (varThree) === (2)` would be considered messy.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm again, this is an **opinionated comment** and is not constructive. Lets not waste further time on it.

Comment: @Rajesh It was just an FYI to help you write cleaner code which is especially important when suggesting code to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are getting from the server is a string of JSON data. You should either change how the response is returned, or you have to parse the JSON twice.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        data = jsonData.coord;
        document.write(data);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', "https://[mon-url]", true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This is the correct conclusion and it's proved by the fact that `document.write(jsonData)` prints a JSON string instead of `[object Object]`

Comment: Ok, it works now, thanks a lot for the explanation !

Comment: 'You should either change how the response is returned, or you have to parse the JSON twice.' I am stringifying the response before returning it to the client side. What is the best way to return a response to prevent having to parse it twice?

Comment: @beano Depends, what server side framework are you using?

Comment: @GökhanKurt I am using Javascript on both client and server (Google Apps Script).

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse if response is a string